# Will this java code cause garbage collection problems, and if so, how can I prevent them?

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I am working on the code below, and the inner class reference linked in the inner class constructor seems as though it might cause a persistent object reference and confuse the garbage collector, do I need to be worried about that in the context here?  Is there a java equivalent of the C# IDisposable where I can clear that link?  Is there a better way to reference a different inner class of a inner class's parent class?  Is there a better structure than inner classes as used here?

```
package com.example.exampleapp.exampleappmodule;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AccelerometerSensorListener a_sensor_listener;
    Button start_listener_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity_layout);

        start_listener_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStartListener);
        start_listener_button.setOnClickListener(new StartListenerButtonListener(this));
    }

    public class AccelerometerSensorListener implements SensorEventListener {

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            //... process sensor data ...
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) { }
    }

    public class StartListenerButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        MainActivity pma;
        SensorManager a_sensor_manager;
        Sensor a_sensor;

        public StartListenerButtonListener(MainActivity argMainActivity) {
            pma = argMainActivity;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // ... get sensor manager and sensor and assign to appropriate class property objects ...
            a_sensor_manager.registerListener(pma.a_sensor_listener, a_sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We're talking about *inner classes* here, not subclasses.

Comment: You're right, I changed the post

Comment: where does **StartStopButtonListener** come from?

Comment: forgot to change that in my simplification for posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a non-static inner class. That means that this inner class already has a reference to the outer class. Supplying the `MainActivity` parameter in the constructor is therefore unnecessary. The only reference to this inner class is in the `View` for which `setOnClickListener` is called. Check out [The Java Tutorials - Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for more information.

As for your garbage collector question, whenever the `MainActivity` instance is garbage collected, its `View`s will be collected as well, and with that the `OnClickListener`. Please bear in mind that this is only true if you do not have any references to the `View` or `OnClickListener` outside the scope of `MainActivity`.

Comment: ok, what should be the syntax for the last code line's `pma.a_sensor_listener`?

Comment: You can leave out the `pma.` part. This reference is explicit. The implicit way is to call `MainActivity.this.a_sensor_listener`. Check out [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: seems to me you have "explicit" and "implicit" reversed above, but regardless, the reference does resolve to the parent class.  Thanks!